# SSRS - How can I group fields all into 1 column?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have an SSRS report which looks something like this:

[image]

I used Row Groups to get the above layout but I need to get the layout to look like the below image. So basically I need the Groups and Sub Groups to all be in 1 column. Is this possible to do in SSRS?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to achieve your expected result by playing around with the grouping settings.

First create a tablix and right click on the second cell of the first column.

[image]

Select Add Group, Row Group - Parent Group. Then just use the following settings.

[image]

Be sure to check Add Group Header checkbox.

Now select the recently created group column (the first) and delete it. Note the groups will remain.

[image]

Once you delete the column you will have two rows in one group. Just use the exprressions and set the bold format for the `Group` cell.

[image]

It will produce the following output.

[image]

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: That worked perfectly! I actually had to add a second subgroup so there were 3 levels. I had to play around with the grouping a little bit to add the 3rd level but I was able to do it using your instructions. Thanks!